# Como referenciar variável de instância com mesmo nome de uma variável local em C++?

Tags: c++, orientação-a-objetos, encapsulamento

Em C++, como eu posso referenciar uma variável de instância que tem o mesmo nome que uma variável global? Por exemplo, em um método set da seguinte classe:

```
class Person
{
private:
    string name;

public:
    void setName(string name) 
    {
        //Em java eu faria: this.name = name;
    }

    string getName()
    {
        return name;
    }
};
```

Comment: Com `this->name ` https://stackoverflow.com/q/6779645/4438007 ; `this` é um ponteiro para o objeto atual

Comment: Exatamente como o @JeffersonQuesado disse, `this->name = name;`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Em C++, existe a [palavra chave `this`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/this). Ela é reservada para contextos em que um objeto está tendo seu método sendo executado.

Esse `this` se comporta como uma constante, constante essa que é um ponteiro da classe de onde o método está sendo executado. Claro, precisa ser um método de instância, métodos estáticos não podem referenciar ao próprio objeto.

> Para ser mais exato, `this` é um [`prvalue`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/value_category)

Na verdade, toda referência a um método de instância ou atributo dentro do objeto é tratado como tendo uma chamada implícita para `this->`. No seu exemplo:

```
string getName()
{
    return name;
}
```

Se usado de modo totalmente explícito ficaria:

```
string getName()
{
    return this->name;
}
```

Entre outras funções, chamar explicitamente o `this` serve para desambiguar. Por exemplo, no seu `setter`, há um parâmetro chamado de `name`, nome de parâmetro esse que "joga uma sombra" sobre a variável de instância `name`.

> Em inglês, diz-se que "the parameter shadows the member with the same name"

Para resolver essa situação, pode-se usar usar o `this` de modo que fique tudo não ambíguo:

```
void setName(string name) 
{
  this->name = name;
}
```

### (Anti-)Padrões C++ de nomenclatura

Devido a problemas desse tipo, algumas escolas de C++ pregam que variáveis de instância devem começar com "`_`". Então se usaria `_name` para a variável e `name` para o parâmetro. De modo geral, seu código ficaria assim (se fosse seguir as diretrizes dessa escola):

```
class Person
{
private:
    string _name;

public:
    void setName(string name) 
    {
        _name = name;
    }

    string getName()
    {
        return _name;
    }
};
```

Eu particularmente acho essa saída pragmática mas feia. Não usaria ela.

Outro uso seria em construtores; para o caso de `Person` ter um construtor que receba como argumento uma `string` referente ao nome:

```
Person::Person(string name) {
  _name = name;
}
```

Porém esse estilo de codificação não usa os recursos mais elegantes do C++ para se construir objetos.

### Usando inicializador no construtor

Saindo do mundo em que há "`_`" antes do nome das variáveis internas, você pode muito bem usar inicializadores no construtor. Por exemplo, no construtor que receba uma `string` e inicializa o atributo `name` do objeto:

```
Person::Person(string name) : name(name) {
}
```

Nessa sintaxe, o atributo `name` é inicializado com o valor entre parênteses, que nesse contexto é o parâmetro `name`. De modo geral, esse inicializador pode ser entendido mais ou menos assim:

```
<assinatura construtor> : <atributo> ( <valor de inicialização> )
```

Onde:

- `<assinatura construtor>` é a assinatura do construtor (`Person::Person(string name)`)
- `<atributo>` é o nome do atributo que será inicializado (o primeiro `name`, que vem antes dos parênteses)
- `<valor de inicialização>` é o valor que será atribuído ao atributo (no caso, o `name` dentro dos parênteses, que corresponde ao parâmetro do construtor)

---

Algumas fontes adicionais de pesquisa:

- [essa pergunta no SOen](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6779645/4438007)
- [essa resposta do @Maniero](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/250901/64969)