# Qual a diferença entre inicializar uma variável nesses construtores? E como colocar um construtor como padrão?

Tags: c++, construtor

Existe alguma diferença ao inicializar uma variável em alguma dessas formas de construtores? E como eu coloco um construtor como padrão (*default*) em uma classe que possui mais de um construtor?

Construtor 1:

```
class Teste
{
private:
    int valor1, valor2;
    float valor3;
public:
    Teste(void) : valor1(0), valor2(0), valor3(0.f) {}
};
```

Construtor 2:

```
class Teste
{
private:
     int valor1, valor2;
     float valor3;
public:
     Teste(void)
     { 
         valor1 = 0;
         valor2 = 0;
         valor3 = 0.f;
     }
};
```

Atualmente estou preferindo utilizar o o método de construtor 1 pois acho mais limpo, muda em alguma coisa?

Comment: Relacionado: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/248436/64969

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Neste caso específico não muda nada. Recomendo o primeiro só para deixar uniforme com os casos que precisa fazer assim.

Em casos de ter membros que precisam ser inicializados e são classes haverá criação de um objeto temporário do valor e depois copiado para a variável e isto é ineficiente. Piora se o tipo do membro tiver um construtor padrão.

Se um membro for declarado como `const` a única forma de inicializá-lo é como no primeiro exemplo, usando lista de inicialização (o nome disto).

[FAQ](https://isocpp.org/wiki/faq/ctors#init-lists).

O construtor padrão é um construtor sem parâmetros.

Não precisa usar `void` para esvaziar os parâmetros em C++.

Comment: Só uma duvida, o primeiro caso tem a questão da ordem? (ou isso depende do compilador ou padrão que usa, ou configuração, não lembro, ando meio enferrujado), por exemplo o erro `will be initialized after`, desculpe se eu estiver falando besteira.

Comment: @GuilhermeNascimento viu os itens seguintes da FAQ? fala justamente disto.

Comment: Agora que me atentei, obrigado, vou ler.

Comment: Não tem como eu escolher qual construtor padrão eu quero em C++?

Exemplo: https://paste.ofcode.org/37rwCgbj4CpENCGmSiBPAAb

Comment: Tá, e daí que ele seja o padrão? O que deseja ganhar com isso?

Comment: Facilitaria mais o uso da classe, por exemplo eu estou desenvolvendo uma biblioteca e desejo deixar ela open source, se eu deixar o construtor mais usado para a classe de forma padrão facilitaria melhor o uso e entendimento dela(classe), assim eu saberia quais os argumentos logo de cara sem ter que ir na classe para ver os argumentos do construtor que eu preciso.

Comment: Não consigo visualizar qual a vantagem disto. Na verdade sequer consigo entender o que significa "construtor mais usado para a classe de forma padrão". Acho que está tentando criar uma solução para um problema que não existe.

Answer (score 0):

O construtor pode atribuir valores para seus membros de duas maneiras:

1. Pode aceitar os valores como parâmetros e atribuir para as variáveis dentro do corpo da função
   construtor, como mostra o exemplo a seguir:

   ```
    #include <iostream>
    using namespace std;

    class Animais {
      private:
          string nome;
          int idade;

      public:
          Animais(string n, int i) {
              this->nome = n; this->idade = i;
          }
          int getIdade();
          string getNome();
    };

    string Animais :: getNome() {
        return this->nome;
    }


    int Animais :: getIdade() {
        return this->idade;
    } 


   int main()
   {
      Animais armazenar("Ralf", 8);
      cout << "Nome do animal: " << armazenar.getNome() << endl;
      cout << "Idade do animal: " << armazenar.getIdade() << endl;
      return 0;
   }
   ```
2. Uma lista de inicialização pode ser usada antes do corpo da função. Por exemplo:

   ```
   #include <iostream>
   using namespace std;

   class Animais {
      private:
         string nome;
         int idade;

      public:
         Animais(string n, int i) : nome(n), idade(i) {}
         int getIdade();
         string getNome();
    };

   string Animais :: getNome() {
     return this->nome;
   }


   int Animais :: getIdade() {
     return this->idade;
   } 


   int main()
   {
     Animais armazenar("Ralf", 8);
     cout << "Nome do animal: " << armazenar.getNome() << endl;
     cout << "Idade do animal: " << armazenar.getIdade() << endl;
     return 0;
   }
   ```